# Can a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that has a vertical asymptote at $x = 5$ but is bounded on $(5,\infty)$ exist, why or why not?

Tags: real-analysis

I think the answer is no because it would have to include the values $<5$, i.e. $(-\infty,5)$, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider variations of the function $f(x) = e^{1/x}$.

Comment: @Hyperion Isn't that function undefined at $x=0$, though? The question specifies that the domain of $f$ must be all real numbers.

Comment: Could such a function exist?  Yes, trivially - $\frac{1}{x-5}$ on $(-\infty,5)$, and identically $0$ on $[5,\infty)$.  I suspect you've got an unspoken restriction, though - what would that be?

Comment: There is no restriction, which is why I think I'm correct in saying that it's not possible

Comment: I've just given you an example of a function that meets your criteria as stated, so either it's possible, or there's some unspoken restriction.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define an asymptote. If it suffices that either one-sided limit is infinite, then the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{5-x} & x<5 \\
      0 & x\geq5
   \end{cases}
$$ satisfies the precise requirement.

Otherwise, if one needs the two-sided limit to be infinite, then no such function exists, since by the definition of a limit, for every $N$, there will exist $\delta$ such that when $|x-5|\leq\delta$, $$|f(x)|\geq N.$$ In particular, $f$ is unbounded on $(5,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question. I've tried to think through it carefully, but others can correct me if I have made a mistake (I am only a high school student). Also, I am aware my answer is very similar to User361424's, although I was already working on it when they posted the comment so I tried to add more elaboration.

Suppose we have a piecewise function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined such that $f(x) = 1/(x-5)$ for $x<5$, and as $f(x)=1$ for $x$ greater than or equal to $5$.

Then $f$'s graph has a vertical asymptote at $x=5$ (the left-hand limit of $f$ at $x=5$ is $-\infty$, and we only need one of the two either-sided limits to be infinite in order to establish the existence of a vertical asymptote).

But $f$ is also bounded for all $x>5$, because for all $x$ in that interval $f(x)$ remains at $1$ and doesn't go to plus or minus infinity.

Therefore, the answer to your question appears to be *yes* ... unless there are further restrictions you did not make clear in the original question (see the comment from User361424).

Comment: No other restrictions. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @MikeKabat Did my response answer your question, or are you still uncertain?

Comment: @MikeKabat If my post answered your question, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.